# how to erase background from image in android?

Tags: android, background, erase

New in image editing..

i want to develop an app like

**https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.outthinking.bgeraser**

and looking for main functionality which is removing background of any image

help me...
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is, that you don't exactly know what you are looking for.

Just search for:
**Background Subtraction**

Thats how it is called.
You can find lots of articles about that.

Come back if you have more detailed questions.

Comment: thank you. Yes i am looking for background subtraction in android..  tell me the best solution for this...

Comment: I guess a common way is to use OpenCV.