# Remove background of capture image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera, android-bitmap

Hi Developers I want to remove the background of photo .but not able to find anything relevant actually I want this type 
http://cloudinary.com/blog/how_to_automatically_and_professionally_remove_photo_backgrounds
of feature in android java code automatically crop and remove the background

Comment: It means that you would like to remove background from images.If so, Could you check this link ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31673660/how-to-erase-background-from-image-in-android?rq=1 http://answers.opencv.org/question/24463/how-to-remove-black-background-from-grabcut-output-image-in-opencv-android/